# Angular Material Slide Toggle Reset

Tags: angular, angular-material

Variables of Component:

```
  editChecked = false;
  editMode = false;
  editMediaMode = false;
```

My current slide toggle:

```
  <mat-slide-toggle
    color="primary"
    [checked]="editChecked"
    (change)="editCard($event)">
    Edit Event
  </mat-slide-toggle>
```

editCard():

```
editCard(ev) {
  if (ev.checked === false) {
    this.editMode = false;
    this.editMediaMode = false;
  } else if (ev.checked === true) {
    this.editMode = true;
    this.editMediaMode = true;
  }
  console.log(this.editMode);
}
```

When I have a successful submission on the form that this toggle is on I am trying to have the toggle switch back to its default grayed out look. However, even if I set `editMode` to false the toggle is still "activated" despite `editMode` being false. I even tried setting the `editChecked` value to false as well when a successful submission takes place but still get the same problem.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How is editMode related to the `mat-slide-toggle`? On the template you dont seem to bind it anywhere. The `[checked]` input of the component is being binded to the `editChecked` variable, which you dont manipulate in the provided code though...

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the post.

Comment: That was the problem. Went right over my head. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution involved add editChecked to the editCard()

```
 editCard(ev) {
  if (ev.checked === false) {
    this.editMode = false;
    this.editMediaMode = false;
    this.editChecked = false;
  } else if (ev.checked === true) {
    this.editMode = true;
    this.editMediaMode = true;
    this.editChecked =  true;
  }
  console.log(this.editMode, this.editMediaMode, this.editChecked);
}
```

And then setting `editMode`, `editMediaMode` and `editChecked` to false when submission was successful.

Thank you @marko and @Jota.Toledo for the help.